# A Word For Someone Who Has Been Hurt By Love, And In Result Hates The Concept Of It?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, psychology

So, I know this is a very advanced question, because I've looked everywhere and cannot for the life of me find the right word I'm looking for.

I'm currently writing an album and I need a word that means a hate of the concept of love, however, not in an evil, bad guy way, more so a sympathetic, saddening way. I need a word that can intricately describe the feeling of being hurt by love, and result in hating the concept of love itself because of the hurt it has brought upon. I don't want any conjunctions or dash mark words (-), I want a full word.

If such a word doesn't exist, that sucks.

Comment: [We don't pick names for things here.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2160/2085)

Comment: There's probably no word specifically for your intended meaning. But the idea immediately reminded me of the Bob Seger song, *Beautiful Loser* (because that's how I view that sort of person). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czIdAcKDZVs

Comment: For a sympathetic, saddening song on the subject of being hurt by love see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ivVJzGgcq0

Comment: @tchrist  a person asking a question can't know that there isn't a word for something.. or at least an idiom.  I'm reaching for something in my memory as it seemed to be such a common 19th century thing along with their  nervous breakdowns (which I also forget the word for)

Comment: "Hurt by love" is, of course, "heartbroken".

Answer (score 3):

The first word that comes to mind is **jaded**.

:: made dull, apathetic, or cynical by experience or by having or seeing too much of something [ *Merriam-Webster's*]

*Jessica was jaded with relationships after her last boyfriend cheated on her.*

Comment: I generally interpret "jaded" to mean having lost interest due to overexposure to the concept.

Comment: Always thought this was the right word, but indeed reading the definitions doesn't really make it sound like it.  I could've sworn there was a better word.  Something more along the line of damaged rather than simply dull.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [**scorned**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/scorn).

> A feeling and expression of contempt or disdain for someone or something.

To use in a common saying... *"Hell hath no fury like a woman scorned."*